# How to minimally move circles so that they don't overlap?

Tags: geometry, optimization, circles

You're given a set of circles, all the same radius, residing at different locations in a 2d space. Some circles are in fixed positions. How do you make sure none of them overlap, minimizing the distance that the circles are moved (ignoring overlapping fixed-position circles)?

Answer (score 1):

The [Voronoi mapping](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram) of the centers of the fixed circles will yield that space in the plane that is available for non-fixed circles to fill.  In particular, the non-fixed circles can be most efficiently moved by moving each center to a line segment of the mapping then moving along that segment until a non-overlap location is achieved.  If no non-overlap is available, continuing along other segments should eventually result in empty space.

Comment: Is this effective when the number of fixed circles is very small? Voronoi mapping is useful for the fixed circles not overlapping non-fixed, but what about non-fixed overlapping non-fixed?

If there were only 2 fixed circles, wouldn't this method put most of the other circles in a long line?

Comment: Not if you add each circle that is placed as non-overlapping to the Voronoi map.  Then two new rays extend from the equicenter of the three circles, and the process continues